# Using the classpath of the `test` configuration of an SBT dependency

Tags: scala, testing, mocking, sbt

I am depending on a scala library, and within it's tests there is a mock object I'd like to use. I've currently just hand copied it into my projects test directory.

My question is: Is it possible to import the mock from test configuration of the library I'm using? (I've tried 'just importing' it but it could not find it in the compile step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use an alternative ivy configuration mapping. This is how it looks like:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.3" % "test->compile"
```

In this example, your project main ("compile") configuration will depend on ivy "test" configuration of your dependency. If you additionally want the standard dependency, you can spell it out like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.3" % "test->compile;compile->compile"
```

See [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Configurations) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the 'testing' portion of the sbt documentation...